# Multiple definition of a const char*

Tags: c++, linker-errors, multiple-definition-error

I get the above message linker error for a global

```
const char* HOST_NAME = "127.0.0.1";
```

I don't think that I have compiled some files twice but here's my definition of the files anyway.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include "connection.hpp"
```

#### connection.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "connection.hpp"
```

#### connection.hpp

```
#ifndef __connection__
#define __connection__
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

const int BUFFSIZE = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);             //Define page size
const char* HOST_NAME = "127.0.0.1";                    //Local host
//Definition of a class
#endif
```

Any help?

Comment: Obviously the name `HOST_NAME` is also defined in one of the headers you include. Put the definition of `HOST_NAME` in a namespace.

Comment: I thought of that too but I used other names e.g. LOL and had the same issue.

Comment: Why not make `HOST_NAME` const so it will get internal linkage?

Comment: I think it's const already

Comment: @BillyGrande: `HOST_NAME` is not const. It points to const data. You're looking for `const char * const HOST_NAME`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You use wrong declaration for your string. You need to make your string a constant, since constants may be defined in several compilation units. This is why compiler does not report the same error for `BUFFSIZE`: `BUFFSIZE` is const, so it may be defined several times in different compilation units. But `HOST_NAME` is not const, so it is reported. `HOST_NAME` will be const if you change its declaration to

```
const char* const HOST_NAME = "127.0.0.1";
```

Then the error should disappear.

---

> `[C++11: 3.5/3]:` **A name having namespace scope** (3.3.6) **has internal linkage if it is the name of**
>
> - a variable, function or function template that is explicitly declared `static`; or,
> - **a variable that is explicitly declared `const`** or `constexpr` and neither explicitly declared `extern` nor previously declared to have external linkage; or
> - a data member of an anonymous union.

This effectively makes the constant "local" to each translation unit in which it is defined, removing the opportunity for conflict.

Comment: Ohhh, now I get it. The pointer was const but not the data. So now we make the data const as well and it works. Thanks a lot guys!! :)

Comment: Actually it was the other way round - your pointer was non-const pointer to const data. I made it const pointer to const data.

Comment: For how many years I have been programming, the const char* means the pointer will be constant and not the data.

Comment: @SauerVoussoir sorry to say but you are wrong. You can find detailed explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const

Comment: Oh my bad, I did not see you corrected @BillyGrande since you did not mentioned him

Answer (score 2):

You have included "connection.hpp" to both connection.cpp and main.cpp. Therefore it (`const char* HOST_NAME = "127.0.0.1";`) is defined in 2 cpp files.

Comment: No header guards does not prevent it.

Comment: Is that a problem? They are two different cpp files.

Comment: @SujithGunawardhane: You're correct. I misread the question as having one cpp file and 2 header files.

Comment: Yes, If you define some variable in a header file it goes to all the cpp files which included.

Comment: You can get this solved by defining "const char* HOST_NAME = "127.0.0.1";" in one cpp file and "extern const char* HOST_NAME;" in the other cpp file. Then you can access it from both cpp files.

Answer (score 2):

> don't think that I have compiled some files twice

Nevertheless that's exactly what happened. You have compiled `connection.hpp` several times, each time you have `# include`d it into some translation unit.

Either add `static` to the declaration, or add `extern` to it, delete the `= somestring` portion, and provide a definition in exactly one source file.